# Connect PHP to SAP R/3 using SAPRFC - Unable to initialize module

Tags: php, sap-erp, saprfc

Goal: use PHP 5.3 to connect to SAP ECC 6
Config: Windows XP desktop. Using SAPRFC PHP open source extension. Added php_saprfc_530.dll to the php ext directory and added extension to php.ini

### On restart of Apache, application event reported this error:

PHP Startup: saprfc: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS
PHP    compiled with build ID=API20090626,TS,VC6

### These options need to match

1. Any way to get this to work without recompiling PHP (ugh)?
2. Anyone is using SAPRFC successfully?
3. Other options to connect to SAP from PHP?

Comment: Any additional info? This isn't much more than "Something went wrong." Go figure...

Answer (score 1):

I cant tell you exactly whats wrong with the php connector since I'm using the java connector. But there is another way: Try exposing the function modules on ERP side as a webservice and then call them via SOAP.

Comment: So the function modules on ECC must be deployed on the public Portal?